# Why won't clojure.data.xml round-trip my svg file?

Tags: xml, clojure, svg

Here is a file **yo.svg**:

```
<svg  width="200" height="200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" stroke="black"  stroke-width="2" fill="red" />
</svg>
```

Both Firefox and Chrome render it as a red circle with a black border. (I don't know what other browsers do though).

Below is some clojure code (version 1.4), which takes that, writes it out to **yo.svg**, parses it, re-encodes it, and writes the result out to **yo2.svg**, which looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

Obviously clojure is making changes. Neither browser will render **yo2.svg**.

I am figuring that I am doing something wrong, but considerable research has just left me bewildered:

I'm wondering why clojure is making these changes, and whether I should ignore clojure.data.xml and just generate xml by hand, or use clojure.data.xml to do the middle bit and write my own headers. Is svg even a type of xml?

Here is my clojure program:

```
(require 'clojure.data.xml)
(let [ xml-picture "<svg  width=\"200\" height=\"200\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\">
<circle cx=\"50\" cy=\"50\" r=\"50\" stroke=\"black\"  stroke-width=\"2\" fill=\"red\" />
</svg>"



      round-trip-picture (clojure.data.xml/indent-str
                             (clojure.data.xml/parse-str
                              xml-picture))]


  (spit "yo.svg" xml-picture)
  (spit "yo2.svg" round-trip-picture)
  (println xml-picture)
  (println "------------------")
  (println round-trip-picture))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is:

```
(clojure.data.xml/parse-str xml-picture :namespace-aware false)
```

That way the parser will treat the namespace tag like another attribute. Otherwise it won't include the xmlns tag in the parsed tree.

Comment: That's just odd. What other freaky-assed tricks is it likely to pull behind my back?

Comment: Check out: http://clojure.github.com/data.xml/#clojure.data.xml/parse-str and http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/xmlnut/ch04_03.htm